# Comparison always false when adding two random numbers and comparing the sum with user input

Tags: javascript, html, random, input, addition

What I am trying to do is to randomize and assign two numbers to variables and add them while displaying the variables to the user. User enters the sum of the two variables and if the input and the sum is the same, user wins. Though, when I compare, the result is always false when I used console.log to see the Boolean value. 
I am using html and JavaScript. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Game A
</title>
<script>
var y = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
var z = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
function myFunction() {
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("demo"));
var z = parseInt(p);
var x = parseInt(y) + parseInt(z);
var q = parseInt(x);
console.log(z===q?true:false);
if(z===q){
alert("Good job!");
}
else{
alert("aw, try again!");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
<br/>
<div id="a" style="display:inline-block;heigh:100px;width:100px;">
<script>
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML= y;
</script>
</div>
<div id="b" style="display:inline-block;heigh:100px;width:100px;">
<script>
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML= z;
</script>
</div>
<input id="demo"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you are reassigned z in your myFunction and adding y afterwards. so that q is alsways bigger than z when y stays 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:`document.getElementById("demo").value` to get the value from the input field.Do not change the value of `z` inside the function by reassigning the new value to it.Try this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
Game A
</title>
<script>
var y = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
var z = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*20));
function myFunction() {
var p = parseInt(document.getElementById("demo").value);
var z1 = parseInt(p);
var x = parseInt(y) + parseInt(z);
var q = parseInt(x);
  console.log(q); console.log(z1);
console.log(z===q?true:false);
if(z1===q){
alert("Good job!");
}
else{
alert("aw, try again!");
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
<br/>
<div id="a" style="display:inline-block;heigh:100px;width:100px;">
<script>
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML= y;
</script>
</div>
<div id="b" style="display:inline-block;heigh:100px;width:100px;">
<script>
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML= z;
</script>
</div>
<input id="demo"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now I see what was I missing. Thank you.